# how to change Font Color- Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can i change the font color of a text inside a tag using a chrome extension:

this is how my manifest looks like:

```
{
 "name":"Change Font Color",
 "description":"Changes font color to red",
 "version":"1",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*","https://www.google.com/*"],
     "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
   ]
}
```

JavaScript file:

```
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gb_id gb_ac gb_g');
    x.style.color = 'red';
    });
```

I am trying to change the font color  of a sections on google's mani webpage to red but my code does not work.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**:

I found the solution. There were two issues:
1)   I was trying to grab multiple classes with the below line. I should have specified just only one class

```
    `var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gb_id gb_ac gb_g');`
```

2)  I needed to iterate through the collection on classes! It returns an array:

```
for (var i =0,len = r.length; i<len;i++)
{
    x[i].style['color']= 'red';
}
```

I hope this info comes in handy to someone int he future!

Comment: Are you trying to get elements with any of the classes `gb_id`, `gb_ac` or `gb_g` or elements with all three classes?

Comment: the tag contains all three classes. With any of the 3 classes would work. I did not noticed that there were 3 different classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document.getElementsByClassName, use document.querySelectorAll

```
 var els = document.querySelectorAll('.gb_id.gb_ac.gb_g');
 for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
   els[i].style.color="red";
 }
```